# What is the difference between export HTTPS=true and set HTTPS=true (react)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

**package.json**

"scripts": {

```
"start": "export HTTPS=true&&PORT=3000 react-scripts start"
```

vs

```
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&PORT=3000 react-scripts start"
```

}

Comment: Besides,  you need to set environment variables in your NPM scripts you can just omit the set or export

Answer (score 1):

`export`: Used to set an environment variable in bash (Linux/Mac).

`set`: Used to set an environment variable for CMD (Windows).

If you want to support both of the environments, you can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and refactor your package.json as following:

```
"start": "cross-env HTTPS=true PORT=3000 react-scripts start"
```

(don't forget to install `cross-env` in the project dev dependencies)